# How to delete files recursively & skip deletion, when subfolder contains .one files?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, directory, delete-file, del

My goal is to delete a file named **Open Notebook.onetoc2** in all folders and subfolders of `Z:` drive, BUT NOT delete that file from those folders, which contain `*.one` files (actual OneNote files).

I have searched for solutions online for that matter, but have not found that and do not know, how to build one such command myself exactly.

I have got this far:

```
for /F "delims=" %a in ('dir /b /s "Open Notebook.onetoc2"') do @if exist %~da%~pa*.one echo del: "%~da%~paOpen Notebook.onetoc2"
```

Seems 99% done, but stuck with the situation, where "if exist *.one" includes the .onetoc2 files into the "search" as well, which is unwanted. I would only like the "search" to find .one files, not .onetoc2 among them, as it is important to skip deleting the .onetoc2 file, if .one file(s) exist in that directory.

Many thanks in advance! :)

Comment: why not be more specific on what you want to on search or match it somehow? `do if "%~xa"==".one" ...` the question is still a little unclear as you first say you want to delete a file named `Open Notebook.onetoc2` then you say your don't and only want to delete `.one` files.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, perhaps this is what you're wanting: `For /F "Delims=" %A In ('Dir /B/S/A-D-S-L "Z:\Open Notebook.onetoc2" 2^>NUL')Do @If Not Exist "%~dpA*.one" Del /A/F "%A"`

Comment: @Compo - you got it! This worked perfectly! :)) Thank you!

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - Thank you as well for well pointing out the way to look at things.

Answer (score 2):

My commented suggestion as an answer to be ran from the [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line):

```bat
For /F "Delims=" %A In ('Dir /B/S/A-D-S-L "Z:\Open Notebook.onetoc2" 2^>NUL')Do @If Not Exist "%~dpA*.one" Del /A/F "%A"
```

Based upon the `For /F` syntax: `For /F ["options"] %variable In ('command')Do command [command-parameters]` we first need to take a look at `'command'`. We want to output all files rooted at `Z:\` named `Open Notebook.onetoc2`, we do that using `Dir`, *(enter `dir /?` for its usage)*. For safety I have excluded any system files or reparse points from that output, and have redirected any error message to the `NUL` device, which prevents any message, should none exist, from being passed to `Do`.

The `For` loop will pass every file as a fully qualified path to `Do` as metavariable `%A`. We want to first verify that along side any file returned, another file with the extension `.one` does not exist. For that we use an `If Not Exist` condition, *(see `if /?` for its syntax)*. `%A` can be expanded to its drive and path only, *(i.e. the parent directory of any returned `Open Notebook.onetoc2` file)*, using `%~dpA`, *(this syntax is available in the `For` command help information, `for /?`)*.

If the condition is met, we delete the file using the `Del` command. As the files could be read only, we use the `/A` and `/F` options, *(see `del /?` for its syntax)*.

---

If you wanted to do the same, but from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), it would look more like this:

```bat
@For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/S/A-D-S-L "Z:\Open Notebook.onetoc2" 2^>NUL')Do @If Not Exist "%%~dpA*.one" Del /A/F "%%A"
```